# Truncating a SQL char value

Tags: mysql, sql, truncate

I hope that someone can tell me what I am doing wrong.

I would like to query my SQL table and receive back a ClassID and a ClassName.

The ClassID is a char(8) and holds values such as **123.45L1** or **350.12**.

I am attempting to shorten that value so that I receive back **123** or **350** only.

Here is my code:

```
    $classSelect = "SELECT LEFT(ClassID , 3), ClassName FROM Class GROUP BY ClassID";   
    $result = mysql_query($classSelect);

    echo "<td><select multiple size='10' name='Class'>";

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
        echo "<option value='Choice'" . $row['ClassID'] . " - " . $row['ClassName'] . "'>" . $row['ClassID'] . " - " . $row['ClassName'] . "</option>";
    }
    echo "</select></td>";
```

Comment: @JoeTaras - possibly to select unique values, though this approach is generally frowned upon because it's a MySQL-only phenomenon that's very much out of line with SQL standards.

Comment: But if you use GROUP BY ClassName must be in group by list. Yes, in MySql it's ok but in other DBMS no. After this, I don't understand what's issue? Our friends wants to show too characters after full stop? I assume ClassName is a field of Class table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT LEFT(ClassID , 3) AS somename, ClassName
```

and then refer it from PHP as `$row['somename']`

Answer (score 1):

If you are seeking to extract the string up to the decimal point, and that might not always be in the same place, you can use MySQL's [`SUBSTRING_INDEX()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) function:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(ClassID, '.', 1) FROM Class
```

If you are seeking to extract the integer up to the first non-decimal character, you can simply [`CAST()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/cast-functions.html) the string and MySQL will do the rest:

```
SELECT CAST(ClassID AS UNSIGNED) FROM Class
```

The benefit of this latter approach is that the resulting column will be of the correct datatype.